# python 3.5 Why is my while loop omitting the first line?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a code where I use a while loop to read in every line in a txt file until a line with nothing in it is seen i.e \n. My txt file and code looks like this:

```
I like cats
But dogs are 
the best

although a tiger 
would make for
an awesome pet



file1 = input("Enter name of file: ") 
openfile1 = open(file1, "r")
data1 = openfile1.readline().strip()
while data1 !="":
    data1 = openfile1.readline().strip()
    print (data1)
```

What I want it to print out is:

```
I like cats
But dogs are
the best
```

but instead it omits the first line and gives me:

```
But dogs are
the best
```

Why is it omitting my first line?

Comment: Because you read the first line before the loop.

Comment: Because you are skipping the first line when you read the line inside the while loop as you've already read the first line outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said you've already read a line once so it didn't show up.

also, there is an easier way of printing file lines.

```
import os

with open('input.txt') as fl:
    for line in fl:
        print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Using the with statement and iterating over lines is the Pythonic way to do this so this gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

move the print statement to before the readline inside the while loop